# How can I change a number to a word in a column of a list in r?

Tags: r

I would like to know how I can change for instance the BMI 26 to "overweight"?  I want to change the list.

Should it be like this? .. is it possible with "ifelse" or another function?

```
underweight = BMI < 18.5,
normal = between(BMI, 18.5, 24.9),
overweight = between(BMI, 25, 29.9),
obese = between(BMI, 30, 34.9),
extreme = BMI > 35)
```

[image]

Comment: You can do this with `dplyr::case_when`.

Comment: like this .. its not working ...
case_when(underweight = BMI < 18.5,
          normal = between(BMI, 18.5, 24.9),
          overweight = between(BMI, 25, 29.9),
          obese = between(BMI, 30, 34.9),
          extreme = BMI > 35))
how do I do the interval? thxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr::case_when` that should work. You were close, but simply need to get the syntax correct.  This will create a new column with these `weight_class` values applied based on the `BMI`.  The final `TRUE` argument means if anything didn't fall into a group it will receive the value of `unknown`.

```
df <- data %>%
mutate(weight_class = case_when(
   BMI < 18.5 ~ 'underweight',
   between(BMI, 18.5, 24.9) ~ 'normal',
   between(BMI, 25, 29.9) ~ 'overweight',
   between(BMI, 30, 34.9) ~ 'obese',
   BMI > 35 ~ 'extreme',
   TRUE ~ 'unknown'
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findInterval` to subset a vector of the words.

```
c("underweight", "normal", "overweight", "obese", "extreme")[findInterval(BMI
 , c(18.5, 25, 30, 35)) + 1]
#[1] "underweight" "normal"      "overweight"  "obese"       "extreme"
```

Data:

```
BMI <- c(10, 20, 27, 32, 40)
```

Comment: but how is it possible to change in a table with various different variables?

Comment: If you table is named `x` you can use `x$BMI <- c("underweight", "normal", "overweight", "obese", "extreme")[findInterval(x$BMI
 , c(18.5, 25, 30, 35)) + 1]`